# angular 2 object key selection

Tags: angularjs, typescript

so i am trying to retrieve data from Api and cant retrieve with key selection

app/app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {httpServiceClass} from './service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Api} from './api';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
providers:[httpServiceClass,HTTP_PROVIDERS]
 })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 private api:Api[];
 constructor(private getservice:httpServiceClass){

 }


 ngOnInit(){
 this.getservice.httprequest()
   .subscribe(data => this.api = data );

  }

  }
```

service file

app/app.service.ts

```
      import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
       import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
      import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Api} from './api';

@Injectable()
export class httpServiceClass{
    constructor(private http: Http){}



    httprequest(): Observable<Api[]>{
        return this.http.get(' http://date.jsontest.com')
            .map(response =>  response.json());
    }
}
```

api.ts

```
export interface Api{
  time:string;
  date:string;
}
```

mytemplate.html

```
<h1 >HTTP : {{api|json}}</h1>
```

returns    HTTP : { "time": "01:52:41 PM", "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1472910761126, "date": "09-03-2016" }

i tried selecting by key

```
<h1 >HTTP : {{api.time}}</h1>
```

returns in console

EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' in [api in AppComponent@0:4]

Comment: you declare `api` as an array of data : `Api[]` in `AppComponent`. Then when you display `api|json` in the template, we see that it is an object. You should first fix your code.

Comment: Am confused now what type should i declare `api` ?

Comment: I think it should be `Api` both in `AppComponent` and `httprequest`. Note that you are not importing `OnInit` event. You are importing `./service` but your file is named `app.service.ts`. There are a bunch of small mistakes like that. Other people having your error are almost always using a `*ngFor` loop somewhere in their template. Are you using it ?

Comment: well the thing is i tired `Api` withou  `[]` and still not working regarding the import of `OnInit`  don't worry about it i was removed  as i was just trying something and forgot to write it back ..the thing is i can already retrieve data from my api but cannot select or filter what  i want  ... no am not using `*ngFor`  i don't want to loop there are only three keys

Comment: and by the way if i tried just `<h1 >HTTP : {{api}}</h1>` in my template i get      HTTP : [object Object]  the only thing that worked was at subscribing my data at the component file  i adde `.time`      `ngOnInit(){
 this.getservice.httprequest()
   .subscribe(data => this.api = data.time );

  }`  output was   HTTP : 06:37:52 PM but that not efficient !! its driving me crazy not knowing what i am missing !!

Answer (score 0):

An interface in runtime is nothing in javascript world. Try changing your interface to class and see if it fixes the problem. Then refractor the code accordingly.